# Latitude D630 Fan Not Working

Tags: kernel

I have a Del Latitude D630 That the fan never turns on. I tried FanControl. pwmsensors doesn’t show anything.

Comment: Add more detail... Did it work before you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: When I had windows (which sucks) the fan did work.